# Check the size of uploaded file in Oracle UCM

Tags: oracle, oracle-ucm, stellent

I need to check the size of the uploaded primary file in Oracle UCM during checkin. 
I tried writing a filter on the event validateStandard and check the value of dFileSize. But the value is null. 
Any ideas what event should I use and which parameter should I check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it, the right combination turned out to be the parameter dFileSize and the event - postWebfileCreation